# .htaccess redirects to main URL with no string

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I need some help. I have link like this.

```
http://www.example.com/a/exampl-xyz/every-one-have-story?xaf26a=98f5e0c5095a3f5c03c85ffdf2defc3b
```

I want these links to redirect to clean URL like this:

http://www.example.com/a/exampl-xyz/every-one-have-story

How can it be done. I have different string with each URL.

```
?xaf26a=98f5e0c5095a3f5c03c85ffdf2defc3b
```

Comment: How are these links generated?

Comment: @AshwinMukhija i am using wordpress.

Answer (score 2):

#### Specific case: Like this, to remove querystring from URL in /.htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^.+$
RewriteRule ^a/exampl-xyz/every-one-have-story /a/exampl-xyz/every-one-have-story? [R=301,L]
```

With the ? appended on the URL, no querystring will be appended to the result URL.

#### For a general URL,

For example, we don't need any URL argument now, all my site is a bare URL, like http://www.example.com/abh/, http://www.example.com/ab/cde/fghi.php, I've no more need
"**?foo=bar&foo2=bar2**", then I use this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^.+$
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}? [R=301,L]
```

Comment: i think it will work with one url ? what about the other url's which i have ? btw i am using wordpress.

Comment: Please give your general URL pattern to be handled, we would add solutions.

Comment: genral url pattern is like this. sorry for late reply
a/exampl-xyz/every-one-have-story

Answer (score 0):

I think this will help you(into your .htaccess):

RewriteRule ^([^?]*)\?.* $1 [R=301,L]

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.  But re-reading your question it’s unclear how the before & after really differ.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/a/exampl-xyz/every-one-have-story/$1 [NC,L,R=301]
```

Comment: i am using wordpress and these links are genrated in wordpress http://www.example.com/a/exampl-xyz/every-one-have-story

and previously i was using another plugin which created too much query string these query strings are generated with sessions. 

now i have too many url's like this and mostly urls have different query string and each one have this ?xaf26a=